# VB.Net: Inverse of the NameOf(variable) operator. Building an array of large numbers of variables

Tags: vb.net

Given a number `n` of string constants, using a `2xn` array to build a kind of "dictionary" where each constant can then be retrieved by its name is straightforward for a small number `n`, e.g. `{{NameOf(CONST_FEN01),CONST_FEN01}, {NameOf(CONST_FEN02),CONST_FEN02}, ..., {NameOf(CONST_FEN15),CONST_FEN15}}`, but becomes an insurmountable task for large `n`. Yet, by choosing names with a regular pattern, say `<name>1, <name>2, <name>3, ..., <name>9999`, it is firstly an easy task to automate the creation of an array containing these variable name/strings and, if there were an operator producing each variable from its name/string (in a way the reverse of the NameOf operator), this would automate the building of the 2xn "dictionary". For what it's worth I am adding a few snippets of code, the final step being wishful thinking.

The string constants might be defined in the source code as:

```
    Const CONST_FEN1 As String = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
    Const CONST_FEN2 As String = "r2qk2r/pp1n2p/2p1p2n1p/3p/3P/B1PB1N/P1P2PPP/N2Q2K w - - 0 1"
    '...
    Const CONST_FEN15 As String = "1r3r1k/6pp/6b/pBp3B/Pn1N2P/4p2P1P/2KR3R/ b - - 0 1"
```

```
    Function BuildNamesArray(ByVal _prefix As String,
                             ByVal _n As Integer) As String()
        Dim names() As String = Nothing
        Dim name As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To _n
            name = _prefix + i.ToString '+ CType(i, String)
            names = HELPER(names, name)
        Next
        Return names
    End Function

    Function HELPER(ByVal _ar() As String,
                               ByVal _element As String) As String()
        'appends the string array
        If Not _ar Is Nothing Then
            Dim Len As Integer = _ar.Length
            If Len = 0 Then
                ReDim _ar(0)
                _ar(0) = _element
            Else
                ReDim Preserve _ar(Len)
                _ar(_ar.Length - 1) = _element
            End If
        Else
            ReDim _ar(0)
            _ar(0) = _element
        End If
        Return _ar
    End Function
```

The following then builds an array `{"FEN1","FEN2",...,"FEN13"}`:

```
    Dim arrNames() As String = BuildNamesArray("FEN", 13)
```

To turn this into `{FEN1,FEN2,...,FEN13}` would require an operator that turns strings `"FEN<n>"` into variable names `FEN<n>`.

Comment: So you want the array to produce code with variables? How do you intend to use this?

Comment: Considering the kinds of things Reflection produces, I am wondering if the system, presented with a string, say ```"FEN999"``` can be made to see if indeed there is a string constant defined having that name and is defined as
```Const FEN999 As String = "1r3r1k/6pp/6b/pBp3B/Pn1N2P/4p2P1P/2KR3R/ b - - 0 1"```
and returns it.

Comment: So you want to check if class has string constant called "FEN999"? (or whatever is in the array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that will find **ALL** `Const`s of type `String`. Note that "cherryPi" is in there to show that it is being rejected:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1

    Const CONST_FEN1 As String = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
    Const CONST_FEN2 As String = "r2qk2r/pp1n2p/2p1p2n1p/3p/3P/B1PB1N/P1P2PPP/N2Q2K w - - 0 1"
    '...
    Const CONST_FEN15 As String = "1r3r1k/6pp/6b/pBp3B/Pn1N2P/4p2P1P/2KR3R/ b - - 0 1"

    Const cherryPi As Double = 3.1415926

    Private LookupValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim FIs() As FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static)
        For Each FI As FieldInfo In FIs
            If FI.FieldType.Equals(GetType(String)) AndAlso FI.IsLiteral Then
                LookupValues.Add(FI.Name, FI.GetValue(Nothing))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim constName As String = "CONST_FEN2"
        If LookupValues.ContainsKey(constName) Then
            Dim value As String = LookupValues(constName)
            MessageBox.Show(constName & " --> " & value)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Const not found: " & constName)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you'd rather have only those that match your pattern, looking for them "by name", then you could do it this way instead:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1

    Const CONST_FEN1 As String = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
    Const CONST_FEN2 As String = "r2qk2r/pp1n2p/2p1p2n1p/3p/3P/B1PB1N/P1P2PPP/N2Q2K w - - 0 1"
    '...
    Const CONST_FEN15 As String = "1r3r1k/6pp/6b/pBp3B/Pn1N2P/4p2P1P/2KR3R/ b - - 0 1"

    Private LookupValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 1 To 15
            Dim FI As FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetField("CONST_FEN" & i, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static)
            If Not IsNothing(FI) AndAlso FI.FieldType.Equals(GetType(String)) AndAlso FI.IsLiteral Then
                LookupValues.Add(FI.Name, FI.GetValue(Nothing))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim constName As String = "CONST_FEN2"
        If LookupValues.ContainsKey(constName) Then
            Dim value As String = LookupValues(constName)
            MessageBox.Show(constName & " --> " & value)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Const not found: " & constName)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for but had little hope of finding it in ```System.Reflection``` without a protracted effort.